# Code run in Python IDLE gives different output to the same code ran in Processing Python mode

Tags: python, compilation, processing

I am currently developing an application for handling equations and for this project I decided to use the Processing development enviroment in Python mode, but i ran into a confusing problem when large numbers were involved. Multiplying two numbers together could just give seemingly random outputs. I then tried Running the code in the standard Python IDLE and it gave the correct answer

The problem occurs when a constant is squared and gives another large number, for example when I run the code in Processing IDE it gives the output different to what the code run in python IDLE

The console output for the same code ran in the different development environments:

Python:

```
[[-4, ['x', 1]], [99999999]]
[16, ['x', 1], ['x', 1]]
[-399999996, ['x', 1]]
[-399999996, ['x', 1]]
[9999999800000001]
[[16, ['x', 2]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [9999999800000001]]
9999998200000081
cost [[16, ['x', 2]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [9999999800000001]]
```

Processing:

```
[[-4, ['x', 1]], [99999999]]
[16, ['x', 1], ['x', 1]]
[-399999996, ['x', 1]]
[-399999996, ['x', 1]]
[9999999800000001L]
[[16, ['x', 2]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [1674919425]]
74919505
('cost', [[16, ['x', 2]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [-399999996, ['x', 1]], [1674919425]])
```

As you can see the number stored in the last index of the cost array is different even although the code is the exact same.

The expected result was the one in the python IDLE.
What I would like to know is if this is a known issue with the Processing IDE and if there is a way to aviod this problem.

Comment: code is the same but interpreter can be different - and it can make a difference. One number has `L` at the end (`L` like `long-int`) and as I remeber in was used in old Python - 2.6 or maybe even older.

Comment: IDE and IDLE it is tools only to create code. After creating program we run it without IDE/IDLE. Just like nobody use IDE to run Excel or Chrome. So more important is if it works correctly without IDE/IDLE.

Comment: You are showing us your output but not your code. We can't possibly reproduce your problem without running the code.